# Finding a clean way to set a value in a node preferably using an algorithm

Tags: c++, std

I have a range of bools in a vector and some vectors with a set size and I want to iterate over the larger vector and insert the values from the large bool vector into the smaller vectors in the nodes.
These are the smaller vectors. And the structure of the nodes

```
std::vector<BrainNode> _inputNodes;
 std::vector <std::vector<BrainNode>> _hiddenNodes;
std::vector<BrainNode> _outputNodes;

class BrainNode
{
float _value{ 0 };
std::vector<bool> connections;
public:
bool operator[](size_t index);
};
```

Is there a nice algorithm mby a std::copy but with a predict or ranged move and removing the moved sub-range? I am happy to any input please share your ideas.

I was thinking of maybe using `std::move` and then rotating and remove but it seems messy.

I have done this, but I know this has to be a better way.

```
std::vector<bool> gaia::NeuralNet::set_input_nodes(std::vector<bool> nodeConactions)
{
    uint i = 0;
    for (BrainNode& node : _inputNodes)
    {
        node[nodeConactions[i++]];
    }
    auto it = std::rotate(nodeConactions.begin(), nodeConactions.begin()+i, nodeConactions.end());
    nodeConactions.erase(it);
    return nodeConactions;
}
```

Is there an algorithm that can remove that part that it moves from?
That works kinda like this?
v is a vector of bools and out is a vector of bools that is a data member in a class.

```
    v.erese(std::algorithm(v.begin(),v.end(),v.begin()+n,out));
    return v;
```

Comment: Is your post an automatic translation ?

Comment: From bool to node? no @Yves Daust

Comment: Would be great if you can provide a sample input and output to better illustrate your idea.

Comment: Also, unless I missed some important thing from your example code, `nodeConactions` was taken by value, so any rotation and erase won't actually affect anything outside of that function. Or maybe you just forgot to return `nodeConations` at the end?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry the output should be a vector of the remaining bools. I forgot that the return statement, but it should return remain a vector of the remaining bools. @Ranoiaetep

Comment: @IsakTrue Since you haven't provided an example, I don't quite understand what exactly you were trying to achieve. However, the last two line, `rotate` then `erase`, you could have simply do `nodeConactions.erase(nodeConactions.begin())` to remove the first element from the vector.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep sorry I don't understand what example you want? The return is the nodeConactions vector.